# R getting difference between two date

Tags: r

I have the following data.frame:

```
employee <- c('John Doe','Peter Gynn','Jolie Hope','Peter')
enddate <- c('2010-11-1','2008/3/25','2007-3-14','2007/9/21')
startdate<- c('','20010101','20010504','19990221')
employ.data <- data.frame(employee, enddate, startdate)
```

I would like to get the difference between `startdate` and `enddate`. How can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
employ.data$enddate <- as.Date(gsub('/','-',employ.data$enddate));
employ.data$startdate <- as.Date(employ.data$startdate,'%Y%m%d');
employ.data;
##     employee    enddate  startdate
## 1   John Doe 2010-11-01       <NA>
## 2 Peter Gynn 2008-03-25 2001-01-01
## 3 Jolie Hope 2007-03-14 2001-05-04
## 4      Peter 2007-09-21 1999-02-21
employ.data$enddate - employ.data$startdate;
## Time differences in days
## [1]   NA 2640 2140 3134
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `library(lubridate)` which can take multiple date formats.  In the example the 'enddate' and 'startdate' all have the same order ie. `ymd`.

```
library(lubridate)
employ.data$Diff <- with(employ.data, as.numeric(ymd(enddate)-ymd(startdate)))
employ.data
 #    employee   enddate startdate Diff
 #1   John Doe 2010-11-1             NA
 #2 Peter Gynn 2008/3/25  20010101 2640
 #3 Jolie Hope 2007-3-14  20010504 2140
 #4      Peter 2007/9/21  19990221 3134
```

Suppose if there are other formats as well i.e. `01-25-2010`, `25/2010/03`, we can use `guess_formats` to get the format which can be used in `parse_date_time` to convert it to 'POSIXct' class.

`ymd` also has other functionalities.  If we check the help page of `ymd` (`?ymd`),

> If ‘truncated’ parameter is non-zero ‘ymd’ functions also check
>        for truncated formats. For example ‘ymd’ with ‘truncated = 2’ will
>        also parse incomplete dates like ‘2012-06’ and ‘2012’.